# passing computed property as prop (undefined)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a `salePrice()` computed property and I'm trying to pass it to the child component. The problem is that the component says that `salePrice` is undefined.

I need it to be reactive but It doesn't seem to be working.

```html
<v-tab-item value="repairs_images" class="px-3 py-3" :eager="true">
    <h2>Repairs & Images</h2>
    <images_page v-if="realestate.id" :realestate="realestate"></images_page>
    <repairs_page v-if="realestate.id && salePrice !== undefined" :realestate="realestate" :salePrice="salePrice"/>
</v-tab-item>
```

And this is the `salePrice` comp. property:

```js
salePrice() {
    if (this.realestate.use_manual_price === true) {
        return this.realestate.manual_price
    }
    return this.realestate.price
},
```

That is being change anytime user changes `use_manual_price`. In debug mode, I see that it works in the App but the changes aren't propagated to the child.

Do you know how to make it work? I also tried to use `this.$root.salePrice` in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work, it would be better if you provided a reproduction link, like a jsfiddle.

Problem could be that your computed property actually returns an undefined value because of `this.realestate` if checks. How are you defining or fetching this value in the first place?

Anyways,can you try:

- Giving the prop definition of `salePrice` a default value, e.g.

  ```
   props:{
    salesPrice: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }
  ```
- Or also add another if-check to your computed property that returns a default value in case `this.realestate.price` is also undefined at that moment of instance.

```
    salePrice() {
    if (this.realestate.use_manual_price === true) {
        return this.realestate.manual_price
    } 
    else if(this.realestate.price){
    return this.realestate.price
    }
     return 'dummy price'
    },
```

As far as I know, props can of course render as "undefined" at first, if the data from the parent component is unavaliable. And if you're dealing with a computed property it could throw the error you've mentioned before the computed property returns a value.

Please let me know!